# How to implement svm model in android?

Tags: android, matlab, model, classification, libsvm

I trained the classifier,in Matlab, with svmtrain and now i don't have a clue how to implement the model it in android. There is not even an example to show how to classify other unlabeled data with svmpredict?
Can any one show how do i test the classifier with unlabeled data and then how to implement the model in android?

Answer (score 0):

There's [libsvm](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) for Java. You can probably use it on Android as it is. You'll have to figure out how to connect it to the output of your Matlab training, but it should be doable.

Just keep in mind Android devices have CPU and memory limits bigger computers don't have, so things might not work as you expect them to.

Comment: I don't want to do the training in the phone, i want to implement the model!